# drawing in surfaceView make some rectangle disappear

Tags: android, android-canvas, surfaceview

why when i draw in canvas (SurfaceView)other thing will disappear? i run it in mainthread and checking if `holder.getSurface().isValid()` but something are shown and somthing will disappear?

```
drwaingCanvas = holder.lockCanvas();
drwaingCanvas.drawRect(startPos.x, startPos.y, endPos.x, endPos.y, paint);
holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(drwaingCanvas);
```

any help aperciated.

Answer (score 0):

you should draw it again and again in different thread.